# Where was the song Dil Dhoondhta Hai from the film Mausam filmed?

Tags: film-location, mausam

I am curious where the song [Dil Dhoondhta Hai](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t4TzZJ8V0JU) from the film [Mausam](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0151511/?ref_=nv_sr_2) was filmed. I saw [this](http://osdir.com/ml/music.pancham/2005-03/msg00235.html) thread but am still curious for a more accurate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The song is shot in **Pahalgam, Kashmir** according to this source (which you may have come across)  http://www.filmapia.com/films/movies/scenes/dil-dhoondta-hai-song

A google search for Pahalgam brings up images very much like those in the song..